# Extra fields are added to redux store because of immutable js, how to stop this?

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6, redux, immutable.js

## Background

I have a react redux application making use of immutable js.

## Problem

For the most part this is working perfectly but some of the reducers in the application are adding several extra fields to my redux store.

## Example

The fields that I can see are as follows

- _root
- __altered
- size

This only happens some of the time. When I use a reducer that also merges the current state.

```
case ActionType.SUCCESS_GET_DATA : {
    let newState = { ...state, [action.meta]: action.payload };
    return state.merge(newState);
}
```

where: `action.meta` is the unique key/name of the data and `action.payload` is the data that is successfully retrieved.

## Question

So I can see that creating a new state with the spread operator is causing these extra fields to be added to my state. So is there a way to use the spread operator without adding these extra fields?

Comment: yeah i just figured that out , funny how writing up a question like this gives you a moment of clarity, thanks Steeve.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

## Immutable maps will always add there own 'meta'

So I have come to the conclusion that Immutable maps will always add there own meta to the state. This is because its a map merged with an object.

To get around this use the method `toJS()`

```
case ActionType.SUCCESS_GET_DATA : {
    let jsState = state.toJS();
    let newState = { ...jsState, [action.meta]: action.payload };
    return state.merge(newState);
}
```

Now you're merging a object with an object.